# Webmock / RSpec - Net::HTTP - How to assert that read_timeout and open_timeout have been set on Net::HTTP instance in method

Tags: rspec, webmock

I am new rspec and webmock user!

I am setting the read and open timeout values for a Net::HTTP instance in a method that I am unit testing:

```rb
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
https.open_timeout = timeout #set the timeout from method parameters
https.read_timeout = timeout

# make request etc.
```

I am using webmock to mock the request to an external api.

How do I check that the *open_timeout* and *read_timeout* properties have been set on the Net::HTTP instance?

I have tried the following in my unit test:

```rb
it "accepts custom timeout period" do
    yamlContent = "image: ruby:latest"
    expectedTimeout = 5
    allow(YAML).to receive(:load_file).with(@fileName).and_return(yamlContent)

    mockHttps = instance_double(Net::HTTP)
    stub_request(:post, @endpointUrl).to_timeout
    
    expect do
        api = Gitlab::Lint::Client::Api.new
        response = api.lint(@endpointUrl, @fileName, @defaultHeaders, expectedTimeout)    
    end.to raise_error(Net::OpenTimeout)

    expect(mockHttps.read_timeout).to eq(expectedTimeout)
    expect(mockHttps.open_timeout).to eq(expectedTimeout)
end
```

This uses webmock to simulate a timeout and I see that a timeout error is indeed being raised. However, I *read_timeout* is an unrecognised property for the *mockHttps* double:

```sh
   Failure/Error: expect(mockHttps.read_timeout).to eq(expectedTimeout)
       #<InstanceDouble(Net::HTTP) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :read_timeout with (no args)
     # ./spec/gitlab/lint/client/api_spec.rb:83:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Does `Gitlab::Lint::Client::Api` have a method that returns `Net::HTTP` instance it uses?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, no the method uses ```Net::HTTP``` to make the request only. The method returns the json reponse from the htt request....

Comment: You'll need access to the Net::HTTP instance in your tests somehow. I can't think of any other way.